# Calculating point density of distinct points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I want to calculate the density of a point layer with QGIS, but these points are dependent on one attribute. (I have different kind of points)

I do not only want the normal heatmap; I need the density of distinct points, because I want to discover hotspots of mixed points vs hotspots of homogeneous areas.

Do you know, if this is possible with normal QGIS?

I have not tried to apply GDAL/OGR in a Python script in order to achieve the objective.

Comment: Does anything oppose creating files only containing these distinct points? Also, like most other vector-tools density should work with selected features only.

Comment: Yes, because I want to know the number of different points in range; NOT the total number of points in range.

Comment: Then I missunderstood your question. Could you rephrase it, maybe add an image of your data structure showing the different classes of points and what you want to know exactly?